# A bounded sequence in $C[a,b]$ (normed by maximum norm) that has no convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

I need to construct a bounded sequence in $C[a,b]$ that does not have any convergent subsequence. Here $C[a,b]$ is equipped with the maximum norm.

Would it be easier if I use some equivalent condition of sequentially compactness in Banach space?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159364/sequence-in-c0-1-with-no-convergent-subsequence) (you can modify the example given there to work on $[a,b]$).

Answer (score 3):

$a=0, b=1$.

$f_n(x) = x^n$, it converges to $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \quad if \; x\neq 1 \\ 1 \quad if \; x=1\end{cases}$$

This $f$ is not in $C[0,1]$, and obviously every subsequence converges to the same limit, therefore does not converge in $C[0,1]$.

For generic $[a,b]$ just adapt the function.

Answer (score 1):

I will consider the case $a = 0$, $b = 1$. You can get the general case by precomposing by a linear transformation which maps $[0,1]$ to $[a,b]$.

The way you should think in these sorts of problems is as follows. We're looking at an infinitely-dimensional metric space. The unit ball has "lots and lots of room". We should find a sequence $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$ of points on the unit ball such that the distance between any two of them is $1$. Such a sequence has no accumulation points, therefore no convergent subsequence.

To make things interesting, let us construct the sequence so that it converges to $0$ on every point. Thus we want:

1. $\lim_n f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and
2. $\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| = 1$.

There are many ways to do this. A common one is to use increasingly narrow "tent functions". Define $t(u,v) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be the function (you *really* should draw a graph of $t(u,v)$):
$$
t(u,v) : x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
  0 & x \leq u \\
  2(x - u)/(v-u) & u \leq x \leq (u+v)/2 \\
  2(x - v)/(u-v) & (u+v)/2 \leq x \leq v \\
  0 & v \leq x
\end{cases}
$$
Now consider the sequence
$$f_n = t(2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n})$$
The norm of every $f_n$ is $1$ because $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$ and $f_n(3 \cdot 2^{-n-1}) = 1$. Furthermore if $n \neq m$ then $0 \leq |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq 1$ and $f_n(3 \cdot 2^{-n-1}) = 1$ and $f_m(3 \cdot 2^{-n-1}) = 0$, therefore the distance between $f_n$ and $f_m$ is $1$.