# Multiplication operator with non-zero continuous function on [0,1] is not compact

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, compactness

For $g \in C[0,1]$, $g \not\equiv 0$ we define the **multiplication operator** 
$M_g: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$, $f \mapsto gf$.

Now I want to show that this operator is not compact.

I know that $(f_n)_n \subset C[0,1]$ with $f_n(x) = x^n$ is a bounded sequence which has no convergent subsequence. However, this is only useful if $g$ is a constant function to show like in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159364/sequence-in-c0-1-with-no-convergent-subsequence/159396#159396) that $M_g$ is not compact. However, it gets complicated if I consider a general $g$ because then I have no idea how to estimate

$||M_g f_n - M_g f_{2n}|| = \operatorname{sup}_{x \in [0,1]} |g(x)| \cdot (x^n - x^{2n})$

from above. If we would estimate with $||g||$ we would get an undesired $\leq$-sign. Could someone help me to find a more appropriate bounded sequence $(f_n)_n$ so that $(M_g f_n)_n$ has no convergent subsequence and thus can not be compact?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let $J=[a,b]$ be a closed interval on which $g(x) \ne 0$.
Let $h$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $h(x) = 1/g(x)$ on $J$, and $f(x) = h(x) g(x)$ which is $1$ on $J$.  Since $M_f = M_g M_h$ and $M_h$ is a bounded linear operator, it suffices to show $M_f$ is not compact.  Now use a bounded sequence of continuous functions  that has no subsequence converging uniformly on $J$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you explain me why we need the (non-) uniform convergence? I have seen this kind of argument before, but unfortunately I don't understand how this works.

Comment: I got it: Convergence of sequences of continuous functions in $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm is actually equivalent to the uniform convergence of these continuous functions.

And for the solution one can the bounded sequence $(u_n)_n$ in $C[0,1]$ with $u_n(x) =\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^n$ on $x \in J=[a,b]$ and constant otherwise (otherwise the sequence is not bounded), so we can imitate the proof which I described before. Could you please confirm?