# Finding a bounded sequence of $C[0,\pi]$ such that it has no cauchy subsequnce

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider $(X,\|\cdot\|) = (C[0,\pi],\|\cdot\|_{2})$ where $\|f\|_{2} = \left (\int_{0}^{\pi} |f(t)|^{2} \,\mathrm{d}t)\right )^{\frac{1}{2}}$ How can I find a bounded sequence $(f_{n}) \in X$  which has no Cauchy subsequence? I'm aware of the question ([Sequence in $C[0,1]$ with no convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159364/sequence-in-c0-1-with-no-convergent-subsequence)) but their example doesn't work for this norm.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Approximate step functions such as $f_n(x)=\tanh(n(x-\frac{\pi}{2}))$ also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for instance $f_n(x)=\sin(n\,x)$.

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If, in a normed space, every bounded sequence has a Cauchy subsequence then the unit ball is precompact which implies that the space is finite dimensional.